# How to use FF_CONSTANT for Force feedback for Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, joystick, input-devices

I am not able to utilize [FF_CONSTANT](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/input/ff.html#querying-device-capabilities) force effect. My try code is:

```
struct ff_effect joy_effect_, joy_effect_2;
if (iwantconstantforce)
    {
      joy_effect_.id = -1;
      joy_effect_.type = FF_CONSTANT;
      joy_effect_.direction = 0x0000;  // down
      joy_effect_.replay.length = 100;
      joy_effect_.replay.delay = 0;

      joy_effect_.trigger.button = 0;
      joy_effect_.trigger.interval = 100;

      joy_effect_.u.constant.level = 65535;
      joy_effect_.u.constant.envelope.attack_length = joy_effect_.replay.length / 10;
      joy_effect_.u.constant.envelope.fade_length = joy_effect_.replay.length / 10;

      joy_effect_.u.constant.envelope.attack_level = joy_effect_.u.constant.level / 10;
      joy_effect_.u.constant.envelope.fade_level = joy_effect_.u.constant.level / 10;
    }
```

I am able to produce FF_SPRING and FF_DAMPER effects with following codes.

```
if (youwantdampereffect)
    {
      joy_effect_.id = -1;
      joy_effect_.direction = 0;  // down
      joy_effect_.type = FF_DAMPER;
      joy_effect_.replay.length = 20;
      joy_effect_.replay.delay = 0;
      
      joy_effect_.u.condition[0].right_saturation = 65535;
      joy_effect_.u.condition[0].left_saturation = 65535;
      joy_effect_.u.condition[0].right_coeff = 65535 / 2;
      joy_effect_.u.condition[0].left_coeff = 65535 / 2;
      joy_effect_.u.condition[0].deadband = 0;
      joy_effect_.u.condition[0].center = 0;

      int ret = ioctl(ff_fd_, EVIOCSFF, &joy_effect_);        // upload the effect
    }

    if (youwantspringeffect)
    {
      joy_effect_2.id = -1;
      joy_effect_2.direction = 0;  // down
      joy_effect_2.type = FF_SPRING;
      joy_effect_2.replay.length = 20;
      joy_effect_2.replay.delay = 0;

      joy_effect_2.u.condition[0].right_saturation = 65535 / 2;
      joy_effect_2.u.condition[0].left_saturation = 65535 / 2;
      joy_effect_2.u.condition[0].right_coeff = 32767;
      joy_effect_2.u.condition[0].left_coeff = 32767;
      joy_effect_2.u.condition[0].deadband = 0;
      joy_effect_2.u.condition[0].center = 0;

      int ret = ioctl(ff_fd_, EVIOCSFF, &joy_effect_2);        // upload the effect
    }
```

I do not find any info about what is constant force effect feels like or when it makes sense to use it.
Can somebody brief its importance and usage?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with joysticks since works with other devices. First I don't see `ioctl` call inside `if (iwantconstantforce)` are you miss it while posting your question here or you forgot to add it inside your program as well? Also, I found a link https://github.com/flosse/linuxconsole/blob/master/utils/fftest.c you can just check how FF_CONSTAN is used and try this at your code. Hope this can help somehow)

Comment: Thanks @NickS. There  is a good chance that I forgot `ioctl` call in my code, I have to go through it again. Thanks for going through my code so meticulously. Soon, I will start working on it again. I will post here if the problem is resolved.